# TFS 2017 : Restructure Source Control Tree Without Baseless Merges?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Right now our Source Control tree looks something like this:

```
Team Project DB
     |
     |___ Hello World DB STABLE
     |
     |___ Hello World DB RELEASE
     |
Team Project Framework
     |
     |___ Hello World Libs STABLE
     |
     |___ Hello World Libs RELEASE
     |
Team Project Windows
     |
     |___ Hello World Windows STABLE
     |
     |___ Hello World Windows RELEASE
     |
Team Project Web
     |
     |___ Hello World Website STABLE
     |
     |___ Hello World Website RELEASE
```

I would like to restructure it to this:

```
Team Project Hello World
     |
     |_____ STABLE
     |  |
     |  |____ Hello World DB
     |  |
     |  |____ Hello World Framework
     |  |
     |  |____ Hello World Windows Client
     |  |
     |  |____ Hello World Website
     |
     |
     |_____ RELEASE
        |
        |____ Hello World DB
        |
        |____ Hello World Framework
        |
        |____ Hello World Windows Client
        |
        |____ Hello World Website
```

This is a very small example of a much larger (and thoroughly mangled) Source Control tree.  All our branches/folders are in different stages of development.  So things will need to be merged UP/DOWN at some point after the code has been restructured.

I've tried moving branches and folders around (obviously testing in a DEV environment) and it seems no matter what I do I always have to perform a baseless merge once I have the code organized.  Does anyone know a way to do this in TFVC that will eliminate the need for baseless merges after the code has been moved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible. What you would like to do is branching/copying/moving folder/file among different projects and create a new structure.

In TFS, you could only  merge to directly related branches(parent or child). There is **no merge relationship** between  branch `STABLE` and `RELEASE` in your case.

You have to pefer a baseless merge, such as use **[tf merge command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/merge-command)**.

```
tf merge /baseless <<source path>> <<target path>> /recursive
```

> ***/baseless***
>
> Performs a merge without a base version. That is, allows the user to
>   merge files and folders that do not have a merge relationship. After a
>   baseless merge, a merge relationship exists, and future merges do not
>   have to be baseless.
>
> *Note Baseless merges cannot delete files in the target. You can manually carry over such changes.*